# Filled Contour plotting of fill variable with ggplot2 with a fixed color scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, r-raster, ggmap

I am trying to plot a facet grid plot of filled contours for my raster data for a color scale ranging between -40 and 40, even though my data ranges between -70 and 120.

The data(MeltedDf.RData) file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jvfegFJcskPnzB6Thdp0jwLiUD-OZ4-S/view?usp=sharing)

However, the plot doesn't plot well (I attached the picture) for the values outside the range. Is there a way to plot these values for this fixed color scale?

Here's my code:

```html
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
load("MeltedDf.RData")

MainStates <- map_data("world")

xlim <- c(-135,-45)
ylim <- c(20,60)

namex <- c(-130, -115, -100, -85, -70, -55)
labx <-  paste0(abs(namex), "\u00B0W")
namey <- c(25, 35, 45, 55)
laby <- paste0(abs(namey), "\u00B0N")

ggplot(melted_df) +
  stat_contour_filled(aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, z = anomaly, fill = after_stat(level)),
                      breaks = seq(-40,40,by=8),na.rm = T)+
  geom_polygon(data = MainStates, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), color = "gray20", fill = NA)+
  geom_polygon(data = map_data("state"), aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group),
               color="gray20", fill=NA)+
  guides(fill = "legend") +
  xlab("Longitude") +
  ylab("Latitude") +
  labs(fill = "Precip Anomaly")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = rev(brewer.pal(11, "RdBu"))[-6])+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.direction="horizontal",
        legend.justification="center",
        legend.box.just = "center",
        legend.position = "bottom")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = NA, linetype = 2))+
  coord_sf(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim,
           label_axes = list(bottom = "E", left = "N"),
           expand =F,clip="on",lims_method= "cross")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=namey,labels =laby)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=namex,labels =labx)+
  facet_wrap(~facet_col, ncol = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: If you really don't want to include these data, the easiest thing to do would probably be to replace the anomaly values in melted_df outside of your range with -40 and 40, respectively.

Comment: Thank you for that! That's a subtle way to address this. I did that prior posting the question. However, I am looking for why this is happening and if there's a solution.

Comment: I think it's happening because when you set breaks [-40, 40] it uses these as limits. There is an `oob` argument for some continuous and binned scales, but it doesn't pass through for `stat_contour_filled`. What do you want the appearance to be?